# What is the most performant way of processing this large text file?

Tags: ruby

When I read a text file into memory it brings my text in with '\n' at the end due to the new lines.

```
["Hello\n", "my\n", "name\n", "is\n", "John\n"]
```

Here is how I am reading the text file

```
array = File.readlines('text_file.txt')
```

I need to do a lot of processing on this text array, so I'm wondering if I should remove the "\n" when I first create the array, or when I do the processing on each element with regex, performance wise.

I wrote some (admittedly bad) test code to remove the "\n"

```
array = []
File.open('text_file.txt', "r").each_line do |line|
    data = line.split(/\n/)
    array << data
end
array.flatten!
```

Is there a better way to do this if I should remove the "\n" when I first create the array?

If I wanted to read the file into a Set instead(for performance), is there a method similar to readlines to do that?

Comment: If you read it into a set, you'd lose order.  Your example makes it look like order is important.

Comment: If you are sure that it will always be there, why don't you check the last 2 characters? Just keep in mind that Linux has \r\n, but you could actually just get rid of the last 3 or 4 characters in your example and it would be faster than do a full regexp

Comment: do you need the full array in memory? how is the processing going to be?

Comment: "keep in mind that Linux has \r\n"? Linux and Mac OS use `\n`. Windows uses "`\r\n`".

Comment: What does "a lot of processing" mean? Why is it important to remove the line-ends? You can always use `print` instead of `puts` when you output the elements.

Comment: @Wug Order isn't important, I should have picked a better example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to run a benchmark test, using Ruby's built-in [Benchmark](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html) to figure out what is your fastest choice.

However, from experience, I've found that "slurping" the file, i.e., reading it all in at once, is not any faster than using a loop with [`IO.foreach` or `File.foreach`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-c-foreach). This is because Ruby and the underlying OS do file buffering as the reads occur, allowing your loop to occur from memory, not directly from disk. `foreach` will not strip the line-terminators for you, like `split` would, so you'll need to add a `chomp` or `chomp!` if you want to mutate the line read in:

```
File.foreach('/path/to/file') do |li|
  puts li.chomp
end
```

or

```
File.foreach('/path/to/file') do |li|
  li.chomp!
  puts li
end
```

Also, slurping has the problem of not being scalable; You could end up trying to read a file bigger than memory, taking your machine to its knees, while reading line-by-line will never do that.

---

Here's some performance numbers:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'benchmark'
require 'fileutils'

FILENAME = 'test.txt'
LOOPS = 1

puts "Ruby Version: #{RUBY_VERSION}"
puts "Filesize being read: #{File.size(FILENAME)}"
puts "Lines in file: #{`wc -l #{FILENAME}`.split.first}"

Benchmark.bm(20) do |x|
  x.report('read.split')           { LOOPS.times { File.read(FILENAME).split("\n") }}
  x.report('read.lines.chomp')     { LOOPS.times { File.read(FILENAME).lines.map(&:chomp) }}
  x.report('readlines.map.chomp1') { LOOPS.times { File.readlines(FILENAME).map(&:chomp) }}
  x.report('readlines.map.chomp2') { LOOPS.times { File.readlines(FILENAME).map{ |s| s.chomp } }}
  x.report('foreach.map.chomp1')   { LOOPS.times { File.foreach(FILENAME).map(&:chomp) }}
  x.report('foreach.map.chomp2')   { LOOPS.times { File.foreach(FILENAME).map{ |s| s.chomp } }}
end
```

And the results:

```
Ruby Version: 1.9.3
Filesize being read: 42026131
Lines in file: 465440
                           user     system      total        real
read.split             0.150000   0.060000   0.210000 (  0.213365)
read.lines.chomp       0.470000   0.070000   0.540000 (  0.541266)
readlines.map.chomp1   0.450000   0.090000   0.540000 (  0.535465)
readlines.map.chomp2   0.550000   0.060000   0.610000 (  0.616674)
foreach.map.chomp1     0.580000   0.060000   0.640000 (  0.641563)
foreach.map.chomp2     0.620000   0.050000   0.670000 (  0.662912)
```

On today's machines a 42MB file can be read into RAM pretty safely. I have seen files a lot bigger than that which won't fit into the memory of some of our production hosts. While `foreach` is slower, it's also not going to take a machine to its knees by sucking up all memory if there isn't enough memory.

On Ruby 1.9.3, using the `map(&:chomp)` method, instead of the older form of `map { |s| s.chomp }`, is a lot faster. That wasn't true with older versions of Ruby, so caveat emptor.

Also, note that all the above processed the data in less than one second on my several years old Mac Pro. All in all I'd say that worrying about the load speed is premature optimization, and the real problem will be what is done after the data is loaded.

Comment: You'd get an upvote from me if you skip the mention of Benchmark. It'll determine what's performant, yes, but it's not key to the discussion. Your other comments are quite relevant though.

Comment: I won't remove the Benchmark comment, because that's an important tool. People slurp files on the assumption that it's faster, but it isn't, and benchmarking is how they prove it to themselves. Since the OP is worried about performance, that's how he can figure it all out.

Comment: @RobertK How can you say `Benchmark` is not relevant in answering a question which begins "What is the most performant way..."?

Comment: @dbenhur Benchmark isn't revelvant because testing what the OP is doing won't really tell him the best way, which Tin Made said isn't necessarily slurping the whole file. Yeah, reading the file all at once might save time on the read operation, but not the rest of the processing.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [String#chomp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-chomp):

```
lines = open('text_file.txt').lines.map(&:chomp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'ld prefer using strip over split in these cases, and doing it right after handling the line for the first time. Using split after readline is overkill imo. So the code snippet would be

```
array = []
File.open('text_file.txt', "r").each_line do |line|
    array << data.strip
end
```

Comment: Reading toklands answer: Me talking about overkill and then suggest strip over chomp ... yeahh

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get rid of the ending newline character you can either [String#chomp](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/String#chomp-instance_method) or [String#rstrip](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/String#rstrip-instance_method). My preferred method would be chomp.

So you can easily do something like:

```
lines.map! { |line| line.chomp }
# or
lines.map! { |line| line.rstrip }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mvelez@argo:~$ cat test.txt
Hello
my
name
is
John
```

One liner:

```
arr = File.open("test.txt",'r').read.split
```

Decomposing this in `irb`

```
irb(main):002:0> f = File.open("test.txt",'r')
=> #<File:test.txt>
irb(main):003:0> file_contents = f.read
=> "Hello\nmy\nname\nis\nJohn\n\n"
irb(main):004:0> file_contents.split
=> ["Hello", "my", "name", "is", "John"]
```